# GetValues as lowercase from Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm writing a google apps script where I get the values from a spreadsheet..but since I need to see if there is a match with a variable, I need to do make sure the values are in lowercase.

```
  var sheet  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var column = sheet.getRange(A:A); 
  var values = column.getValues();
```

then I want to loop through the values to see if there is a match, like this:
row=0;

```
  while ( values[row] && values[row][0] !== data ) {

     // do something
    row ++;
  }
```

My question is this..while I can make sure the variable "data" is lowercase, how can I make sure values[row] and values[row][0] are also lowercase?

Answer (score 10):

You can loop through the values with checking lower case item,

```
for (var row in values)
{
    if(values[row][0].toString().toLowerCase() !== data ) 
    {
         // do something
    }
}
```

this is `values[row]` an array, what do you mean by lower case of it?

Answer (score 1):

So first of all I believe that with the notation you're using `.getRange` would take a string like `"A:A"` as an argument to return the range containing all values in column A.

- Use `Logger.log()`and `typeof` to check the type of the values being returned.
  `values` will be a two-dimensional array, with each child array containing the value for each respective cell.
- `values[row]` will return an *array* representing the cell at the index of `row`. An array cannot be lowercase obviously.
- `values[row][0]` will return the value in the cell. You can coerce the value to a string (to make sure it's always a string) by concatenating it with an empty string `(values[row][0]+"")`, and then you can apply the usual built-in JS [toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) method, like so: `(values[row][0]+"").toLowerCase();`
- So  `(values[row][0]+"").toLowerCase() !== data` should achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I use this :)

```
function onEdit(spreadsheet) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var range = spreadsheet.getRange("F3:F");
  var data  = range.getValues();

  for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
      data[row][col] = (data[row][col]).toString().replace(/á|à|ã|ä|A/gi, 'a');
      data[row][col] = (data[row][col]).toString().toLowerCase();
   }
  }
  range.setValues(data);
}
```